# Eclipse PHP Debug editor fails to open when stepping through code

Tags: php, eclipse, ubuntu

I'm new to Eclipse, but I've been getting a feel for how the editor works over the past week or two. Everything has been working fine up to now (although Eclipse does occasionally crash - is this normal?). Today the editor failed to open when stepping into code contained in an included file. Instead, a new tab opens with the following error message:

> Could not open the editor: The class file is not on the classpath

*Environment:*

- Ubuntu 11.10
- Eclipse 3.7.1 (installed by download rather than through
  the package system)

If it matters, prior to the occurrence of this error the editor would open successfully, but it would not highlight any syntax (which would be nice).

I've done some searching, but since I'm new to eclipse I haven't dug up anything that looks relevant. Can someone help me troubleshoot this error?

**New Details**
I just discovered that renaming the included file from *.class* to *.inc* or *.php* fixes the problem, so it appears to be a file association issue. How can I properly associate *.class* files with the debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse is not happy with using .class extensions since that is commonly used in java development and eclipse is often used for java development. [This page](http://codex.gallery2.org/Gallery2%3aEclipse_Tutorial#Adding_PHP_Syntax_Highlighting_for_.class_Files) describes various ways to try and get around this. However, I would consider switching to another extension.

Comment: At this point I'm not going to bother with it any more, I'll just use *.class.inc.